# Unable to access Google Home Mini after Wifi password change

Tags: google-home

I had to change my Wifi password on account of security issues. Two of my Google Home Mini devices are now unable to access the wifi, and I'm unable to set the changed password on these two devices through the Google Home app.

Short of resetting the devices, is there some way that I can change the Wifi password stored in these devices? Currently they both are periodically announcing that "I'm unable to connect to the wifi. Pls check network settings through the Google Home App".